# Dropping Data into Aggregate Buckets by Date and Category

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display aggregate counts of open and closed IT tickets by date and category.

Parent table consists of the following columns:

```
Alert_ID     Alert_Open_Date     Alert_Closed_Date
```

I'd like my end result to resemble the following, where I have

A.  A date within any specified date range,

B.  total number of alerts that still showed open as of that date (Outstanding_Alerts),

C.  total number of alerts that were opened on that date (New_Alerts),

D.  total number of the new alerts that were closed on that date (Closed_New_Alerts), and

E.  combined number of alerts, both new and old, that were closed on that date (Closed_Total):

```
  Date     Outstanding_Alerts     New_Alerts     Closed_New_Alerts     Closed_Total
6/1/2018       20                      10             5                     7
6/2/2018       23                      20             8                     10
6/3/2018       33                      13             10                    15
  etc.         #                       #              #                     #
```

I was thinking of something like the following conceptual query to accomplish this, but I'm stumbling over the logic to get the results I'd like.  Regardless of wording I can't seem to get the buckets correct.  Some columns remain blank when they should be populated, for example.  Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    alert_date
  , SUM(OOA)                AS Outstanding_Open_Alerts
  , SUM(NOA)                AS New_Open_Alerts
  , SUM(CNA*NOA)            AS Closed_New_Alerts
  , SUM(CT)                 AS Total_Closed_Alerts
  , SUM(CNA+NOA-CT)         AS Remaining_Alerts  --optional column

 FROM

 (SELECT
      TRUNC(open_date) AS Alert_Date
    , CASE WHEN alert_date < trunc(SYSDATE)-1 AND closed_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END AS      OOA     --old open alerts
    , CASE WHEN alert_date > trunc(SYSDATE)-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END AS      NOA     --new open alerts
    , CASE WHEN closed_date >= trunc(SYSDATE)-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END AS      CNA     --closed new alerts
    , CASE WHEN closed_date < trunc(SYSDATE)-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END AS      CT      --closed total
    FROM sys_alerts)

GROUP BY alert_date;
```

Comment: Is (E) just the alerts that were closed on that day, or the cumulative alerts that have been closed up to and including that day?

Comment: Closed on just that day.  Basically I wan to know how many alerts were closed that day, and of that number, how many of those were new.  Hence the two closed columns.

Comment: You are using sysdate in your query but showing results for multiple dates. Are you trying to get data for all dates in a range, and what is that range? I'm not sure how your results are working, i can't get the numbera to work, so might well be missing something. A smaller set of raw data and expected results for that data would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following your description, to get the numbers for an arbitrary date supplied as `some_date` you want something like:

```
SELECT
    some_date AS Alert_Date
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN open_date < some_date
      AND (closed_date IS NULL OR closed_date > some_date
      THEN alert_id END) AS Current_Open_Alerts
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN open_date >= some_date
      AND open_date < some_date + 1
      THEN alert_id END AS New_Alerts
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN open_date >= some_date
      AND open_date < some_date + 1
      AND closed_date < some_date + 1
      THEN alert_id END AS Closed_New_Alerts
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN closed_date >= some_date
      AND closed_date < some_date + 1
      THEN alert_id END AS Closed_Total
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN open_date < some_date + 1
      AND (closed_date IS NULL OR closed_date >= some_date + 1
      THEN alert_id END) AS Alerts_Remaining
FROM sys_alerts
GROUP BY some_date
```

I've used a count rather than a sum, which relies on the fact that count ignores nulls - and left the default from the case expresssions as null. It doesn't need a sunquery really so I've removed that.

It seems like you want all data for a range of dates, so you can generate that in an inline view or CTE and then join to your real table, so `some_date` becomes wach individual date from that generated range. E.g. to get the last 30 days something like:

```
FROM (
    SELECT sysdate - level AS some_date
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 30
LEFT JOIN sys_alerts
ON closed_date IS NULL OR closed_date >= some_date
GROUP BY some_date
ORDER BY some_date
```

or you could do something with `cross apply` or a partitioned outer join. Hopefully this gives you a starting point though.

Comment: After testing a few options, I think this gives me a useful starting point.  Thanks